# How to check thet the set is closed but not clopen

Tags: open-map, closed-map

It is clear how to proof that the set $A$ is open. I just need to find some sequence which elements belong to $A$ while its limit does not.

It is also clear that in order to show that the set $A$ is closed I need to verify that its complement $\overline{A}$ is open.

But sometimes while the set $A$ complement $\overline{A}$ is open the complement $\overline{\overline{A}}$ of this complement $\overline{A}$ is also open. So we get  [clopen set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clopen_set).

I want to show that the set $A$ is closed but not clopen. Is it enough to show that $\overline{A}$ is open and $\overline{\overline{A}}$ is closed?  And why it is not follows immidiately that $\overline{\overline{A}}$ is closed if I had previously shown that $A$ is closed?

Maybe it exist some very simple while sophisticated example of clopen set? It is not clear to me how the set $\overline{\overline{A}}$ could be open while the set $A$ is closed while them should be the same sets.

Will be very greatfull for help!

Comment: I'm confused with your  notation.Do you mean $\overline{A} = X \setminus A$   ? where $X$ is a whole space

Comment: Yes, that is right

Comment: Actually $X \setminus (X \setminus  A)=A$. So what do you want? you need counterexamples of clopen sets?

Comment: I just can't understand how the set could be clopen and how to show that the set is closed but not clopen.

Comment: Which set, specifically, in which topology?

Comment: I need something very basic

Answer (score 1):

Your first sentence is wrong: what you wrote (not being closed under sequential limit) means the set *is not* (sequentially) *closed*, which is **not the same** as being open. (My topology prof used to say 'a set is not a door.' - because a door is either open or closed, as opposed to a set in a topological space.)

Instead, to prove a set $A$ is open, we need to find a *basic open set* $U$ (given by a 'basis' for the topology) for each $a\in A$ such that $a\in U\subseteq A$.

The basic open sets in a Euclidean space are the *open balls* $B_r(x)=\{v:\|v-x\|<r\}$.

In particular in $\Bbb R$ these are the open intervals, and for instance, $\Bbb Q$ is neither open nor closed.

When a nontrivial clopen set $A$ exists in a top.space $X$, the space is called *disconnected* (we have 2 complementary, nonempty open sets, $A$ and $\bar A=X\setminus A$).
 For example, consider $X:=(-1,1)\setminus\{0\}$ with the usual topology (inherited from $\Bbb R$), it's the union of 2 nonempty open sets $(-1,0)$ and $(0,1)$, hence both are clopen *in* $X$.